# Woocommerce category filter toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

At this URL https://www.floordepot.cl/search/ WordPress with WooCommerce, I have a display of all products. Each product has a lot of categories. These categories are classes that are reflected in the CSS styled buttons above the product list. I've somewhat managed to toggle products by clicking any of the buttons, but what makes it hard for me is what method should I use to add up these filters. In simple words, I need a toggle switchboard.

(I should start my document by hiding the categories I will not use and enabling the view of all other categories by default)

By example, I have a product with class categories .cat-bri .cat-mur and .cat-por

By clicking the button associated with any of those classes I should toggle on all the products with any of those classes, and if a product has one of those classes it should hide if I toggle it back.

But what if I have several buttons active at once?

This is my code so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.product_cat-adhesivos').css("display", "none");
    jQuery('.product_cat-cornisas').css("display", "none");
    jQuery('.product_cat-terminaciones').css("display", "none");
    jQuery(".bot-opa").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-opaco').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.opatiton, .opatitoff').toggle();
    });
    jQuery(".bot-bri").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-brillante').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.brititon').toggleClass("brititon brititoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-pis").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-pisos').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.pistiton').toggleClass("pistiton pistitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-mur").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-muros').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.murtiton').toggleClass("murtiton murtitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-int").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-interior').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.inttiton').toggleClass("inttiton inttitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-ext").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-exterior').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.exttiton').toggleClass("exttiton exttitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-liv").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-living').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.livtiton').toggleClass("livtiton livtitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-com").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-comedor').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.comtiton').toggleClass("comtiton comtitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-dor").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-dormitorio').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.dortiton').toggleClass("dortiton dortitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-ban").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-bano').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.bantiton').toggleClass("bantiton bantitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-ter").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-terraza').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.tertiton').toggleClass("tertiton tertitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-jar").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-jardin').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.jartiton').toggleClass("jartiton jartitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-mad").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-madera').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.madtiton').toggleClass("madtiton madtitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-cem").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-cemento').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.cemtiton').toggleClass("cemtiton cemtitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-pie").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-piedra').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.pietiton').toggleClass("pietiton brititoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-flo").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-flotante').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.flotiton').toggleClass("flotiton flotitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-vin").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-vinilico').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.vintiton').toggleClass("vintiton vintitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-cer").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-ceramica').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.certiton').toggleClass("certiton certitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-por").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-porcelanato').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.portiton').toggleClass("portiton portitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-gre").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-gres').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.gretiton').toggleClass("gretiton gretitoff");
    });
    jQuery(".bot-fac").click(function(){
        jQuery('.product_cat-fachaletas').toggle(); 
        jQuery('.factiton').toggleClass("factiton factitoff");
    });
});
```

```
.titico{
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:62px;
    font-size:11px;
  }
  .opatiton .brititon .inttiton .exttiton .pistiton .murtiton .dortiton .livtiton .comtiton .bantiton .tertiton .jartiton .madtiton .cemtiton .pietiton .certiton .portiton .gretiton .factiton{
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:normal;
  }
  .opatitoff .brititoff .inttitoff .exttitoff .pistitoff .murtitoff .dortitoff .livtitoff .comtitoff .bantitoff .tertitoff .jartitoff .madtitoff .cemtitoff .pietitoff .certitoff .portitoff .gretitoff .factitoff{
    color:#e63946;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
  .boton{
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .botoff{
    display:none;
  }
  .cajaico{
    display: inline-block;
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    max-width:64px;
    border:0px solid #ffffff !important;
  }

.bot-opa {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/opaco.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-opa:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}
  
  .bot-opa:after {
   content: "Opaco";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000000;
    display: block;
}

.bot-bri {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/brillante.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-bri:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-int {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/interior.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-int:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-ext {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/exterior.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-ext:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-pis {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/pisos.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-pis:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-mur {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/muros.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-mur:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-liv {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/living.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-liv:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-com {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/comedor.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-com:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-dor {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dormitorio.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-dor:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-ban {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/bano.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-ban:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-ter {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/terraza.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-ter:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-jar {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/jardin.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-jar:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-mad {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/masera.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-mad:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-cem {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/cemento.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-cem:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-pie {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/piedra.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-pie:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-flo {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/pisoflotante.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-flo:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-vin {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/pisovinilico.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-vin:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}
.bot-cer {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/ceramica.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-cer:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-por {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/porcelanato.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-por:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-gre {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/gres.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-gre:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}

.bot-fac {
     background: url('https://www.floordepot.cl/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/fachaletas.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    height:62px;
    width:62px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bot-fac:hover {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(256,256,256,.8);
}
```

```
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-opa" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-opa" class="opatitoff titico">Opaco</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-bri" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-bri" class="brititoff titico">Brillante</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-int" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-int" class="inttitoff titico">Interior</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-ext" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-ext" class="exttitoff titico">Exterior</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-pis" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-pis" class="pistitoff titico">Pisos</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-mur" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-mur" class="murtitoff titico">Muros</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-liv" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-liv" class="livtitoff titico">Living</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-com" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-com" class="comtitoff titico">Comedor</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-dor" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-dor" class="dortitoff titico">Dormitorio</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-ban" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-ban" class="bantitoff titico">Baño</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-ter" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-ter" class="tertitoff titico">Terraza</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-jar" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-jar" class="jartitoff titico">Jardín</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-mad" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-mad" class="madtitoff titico">Madera</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-cem" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-cem" class="cemtitoff titico">Cemento</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-pie" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-pie" class="pietitoff titico">Piedra</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-flo" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-flo" class="flotitoff titico">Flotante</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-vin" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-vin" class="vintitoff titico">Vinílico</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-cer" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-cer" class="certitoff titico">Cerámicos</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-por" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-por" class="portitoff titico">Porcelanato</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-gre" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-gre" class="gretitoff titico">Gres</span></td></tr></table>
<table class="cajaico" colspan="0" celspan="0" border="0"><tr><td><input class="bot-fac" type="button" value=""/><span id="titico-fac" class="factitoff titico">Fachaletas</span></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: In this case, `toggleClass()` will not help you that much. You can check if the button is active or not, each time you press it, in order to define if you should add or remove the respective classes. You can add an extra attribute in each button e.g. `button-active`, which will take values such as `0` or `1` depending on if it's active or not, and update that attribute, every time you press that button.

Comment: I started from scratch and i have this `code`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var opa = 1;
 var bri = 1;
 var pis = 1;
 jQuery('.product_cat-adhesivos').css("display", "none");
 jQuery('.product_cat-cornisas').css("display", "none");
 jQuery('.product_cat-terminaciones').css("display", "none");
 jQuery(".bot-opa").click(function(){
     if(opa == 1){
      opa = 0;
     }
 });
 jQuery(".bot-bri").click(function(){
     if(bri == 1){
      bri = 0;
     }
 });
 jQuery(".bot-pis").click(function(){
     if(pis == 1){
      pis = 0;
     }
 });
});`code`

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. As you can see, presenting more than small snippets of code in a comment is doomed. Just [include in your question post everything needed to invite useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).